# xslt transform of dynamic xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml similar to the one as follows

```
<DataSet1>
    <Table1>
        <Column1>Value111</Column1>
        <Column2>Value112</Column2>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <Column1>Value121</Column1>
        <Column2>Value122</Column2>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <Column1>Value131</Column1>
        <Column2>Value132</Column2>
    </Table1>
    <Table2>
        <Column1>Value211</Column1>
        <Column2>Value212</Column2>
    </Table2>
    <Table2>
        <Column1>Value221</Column1>
        <Column2>Value222</Column2>
    </Table2>
    <Table2>
        <Column1>Value231</Column1>
        <Column2>Value232</Column2>
    </Table2>
</DataSet1>
```

Where Table1 and Table2 are added dynamically in the dataset. So there can be n number of tables in dataset as Tablen.

I want to write xsl which produces the html as follows

```
Table1
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Value111</td>
        <td>Value112</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value121</td>
        <td>Value122</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value131</td>
        <td>Value132</td>
    </tr>   
</table>

Table2
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Value211</td>
        <td>Value212</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value221</td>
        <td>Value222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value231</td>
        <td>Value232</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way to select xsl template as select="DataSet1/Table*" which can match with any table and iterate the structure?

Please help!!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kTableByName" match="*[starts-with(name(),'Table')]"
  use="name()"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kTableByName', name())[1])
     ]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;', name(), '&#xA;')"/>
  <table>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kTableByName', name())" mode="inGroup"/>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Table')]" mode="inGroup">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="inGroup"/>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'Table')]/*" mode="inGroup">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </td>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<DataSet1>
    <Table1>
        <Column1>Value111</Column1>
        <Column2>Value112</Column2>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <Column1>Value121</Column1>
        <Column2>Value122</Column2>
    </Table1>
    <Table1>
        <Column1>Value131</Column1>
        <Column2>Value132</Column2>
    </Table1>
    <Table2>
        <Column1>Value211</Column1>
        <Column2>Value212</Column2>
    </Table2>
    <Table2>
        <Column1>Value221</Column1>
        <Column2>Value222</Column2>
    </Table2>
    <Table2>
        <Column1>Value231</Column1>
        <Column2>Value232</Column2>
    </Table2>
</DataSet1>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
Table1
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Value111</td>
      <td>Value112</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value121</td>
      <td>Value122</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value131</td>
      <td>Value132</td>
   </tr>
</table>
Table2
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Value211</td>
      <td>Value212</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value221</td>
      <td>Value222</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value231</td>
      <td>Value232</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian Grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [w3Schools tutorial on xPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)? There is a * selector which will allow you to select all children of a certain node like so: `DataSet1/*`